# how to format date format of a foreach php statement

Tags: php

I have read many ways to do this when the date is a simple variable, but how would I format the date to read "M, j" meaning "May, 5" when my php statement is the following?

```
echo "$row->nick $row->lastname, ($row->updated_at)";
```

that now outputs this:

> John Smith, (2017-05-10 12:18:12)

I want it to read:

> John Smith, (May 10)

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen the `date()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [php date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```
echo date('M j', strtotime($row->updated_at));
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `$row->updated_at` is now a string.
You can change it into a DateTime object;

```
$updated_at = new DateTime($row->updated_at);
```

Now you're able to format it the way you want.

```
echo $updated_at->format('M j');
```

Comment: this seemed to work but all of the dates were the same instead of being different 'foreach', I presume from making "updated_at" a global variable

Comment: Make sure you put the $updated_at = inside the foreach loop. It'll create a new DateTime object for every row, so they won't be the same.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `DateTime::format()`

```
$date = new DateTime($row->updated_at);
echo "$row->nick $row->lastname, ($date->format('M j'))";
```

Comment: If you want to remove the error `Undefined property: DateTime::$format` then try  `echo "$row->nick $row->lastname, ({$date->format('M j')})";`